# 3.5" Simulator in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I have currently updated my Xcode from 5.1.1 to 6.0.1 to support apps for iOS 8.0. But I could not find any 3.5" simulator. Is the 3.5" simulator has been removed, or Apple is not going to support the 3.5" iPhone Devices any more?

Answer (score 6):

You can pick the iphone 4S, which has a 3.5" screen.

Answer (score 4):

For XCode 6 and onwards XCode has simulators based on devices as shown in following screenshot

[image]

Apple is still supporting iPhone 4s with latest iOS 8  , so you can select that

Answer (score 2):

From Xcode 6 beta onwards apple have added simulators with device names so you can pick iPhone 4s for 3.5" simulator and iPhone 5 for 4" simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads

There you can download the simulator for the iOS which you want.

[image]